# Javascript international calculations?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have a javascript function that gets three values from text fields in a form, sums them, and displays the sum in the form:

```
function sumVals(theForm) {
    var sum = 0.0;
    sum += parseFloat(theForm.val01.value);
    sum += parseFloat(theForm.val02.value);
    sum += parseFloat(theForm.val03.value);
    theForm.sumvals.value = sum.toNiceFixed(4);
}
```

The function works fine on any computer with an English OS.  For example, if I enter values of 0.2, 0.4, and 0.4 for val01, val02, and val03 in the form, the sumvals field displays 1.000

However, on a computer with an Italian or German OS, if I enter the same values of 0.2, 0.4, and 0.4 for val01, val02, and val03 in the form, the sumvals field displays 10000.000

I think this has something to do with the ways that some non-English OS's interpret periods and commas in numbers.  However, if I try to substitute commas for periods when I enter the values in the text field (e.g. 0,4) then the field switches to a 0 as soon as I take the focus away from it.

I have checked out a bunch of sites dealing with i18n for javascript, but I can't find anything that deals with this specific question, or at least I didn't recognize it as such.

Can anyone help me with a workaround that will easily interpret javascript variables in the native language of the operating system (if that really is the problem)?

Comment: Why would you have the same number format in different cultures? How the browser should guess  what did you mean under some particular number? In German number format is 0,4 (comma as a separator)

Comment: I don't think that `toNiceFixed` method is standard. Is it part of some library you are using? Can you check if `sum` is being calculated correctly by printing it to the console befor eformatting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toFloat(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'));
}
function sumVals(theForm) {
  var sum = 0.0;
  sum += toFloat(theForm.val01.value);
  sum += toFloat(theForm.val02.value);
  sum += toFloat(theForm.val03.value);
  theForm.sumvals.value = sum.toNiceFixed(4);  
}
```